# Ideal solution fugacity coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics

I am super confused about ideal solution behavior. I know that an ideal solution implies that pure component fugacity is equal to the mixture fugacity but apparently that does not mean that the fugacity coefficient is always equal to 1 (ideal gas). So then, how is it possible to calculate the fugacity coefficient of a mixture of vapor in an ideal solution?

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal solution, the fugacity of a component in the mixture is equal to the fugacity of the pure component at the same temperature and pressure as the mixture times the mole fraction of the component in the mixture.

Comment: In other words, @EvanLowry, do a Google search on K values.